# Question about equivalence of two expressions for the Quantum Fourier transformation

Tags: it.information-theory, quantum-computation

The Quantum Fourier transformation on $n$ qubits is just the discrete Fourier transformation,
$$
|j \rangle \mapsto \frac 1 {\sqrt 2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e^{2\pi ijk/2^n}|k\rangle.
$$
In binary notation, this is claimed to have the form
$$
|j_1j_2...j_n\rangle \mapsto \frac 1{2^{n/2}} \bigotimes_{l=1}^n (|0\rangle + e^{2\pi i\;0.j_{n-l+1}j_n}|1\rangle),
$$
where
$$
0.j_l...j_m := j_l/2 + j_{l+1}/4
 + ... + j_m/2^{m-l+1}.
$$
This claim is, for instance, in

*Nielsen, Michael A.; Chuang, Isaac L.*, Quantum computation and quantum information, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-63503-9/pbk; 0-521-63235-8/hbk). xxvi, 676 p. (2000). [ZBL1049.81015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1049.81015).

Section 5.1, formula (5.4), but also in many other texts, talks, and videos, often without proof.

**I do not understand the equality between these two expressions of the Quantum Fourier transformation, can somebody please explain it?**

In the proof contained in the book referenced above, I cannot follow the very last step, from (5.9) to (5.10), which seems to follow from an equality
$$
j2^{-l} = 0.j_l...j_n
$$
which does not seem to be correct, at least not given the above definition of $0.j_l...j_n$: the left hand side contains $n$ summands, while the right hand side only contains $n-l+1$ summands. Another problem I have with that reference are the missing tensor symbols in (5.4) and (5.10), why have they been dropped?

Probably I just misunderstand a simple thing, but I can't resolve it!

Comment: It's not $j2^{-l} = 0.j_1\ldots j_n$ that is being used (that's incorrect, as you said). It's that the fractional parts (in base 2) of $j2^{-l}$ and $0.j_{n-l+1}\ldots j_n$ are the same. If the fractional parts of two numbers $x$ and $y$ are the same, then $e^{2\pi ix} = e^{2\pi iy}$, so the proof goes through.

Comment: As for why the tensor product symbols are omitted in (5.4) and (5.10): that's just a common convention in quantum information theory when there's no confusion about which product could be meant, especially when the equations are very long (like (5.4) and (5.10)). Since you can't multiply vectors in the usual matrix multiplication way, the tensor product is what must be meant in those equations.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: thanks, your first comment resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

The binary representation of the $n$-qubit quantum Fourier transform is worked out step-by-step for three qubits in [these lecture notes](https://www.physik.fu-berlin.de/en/einrichtungen/ag/ag-eisert/teaching/ws20-21/solution09.pdf) (page 2). The generalization to higher $n$ should be obvious from the construction presented there.